# Selenium IDE: sign out button not working

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

sign out button is not responding in selenium ide

```
Error:
""
clickAt(locator, coordString)
    Arguments:

        locator - an element locator
        coordString - specifies the x,y position (i.e. - 10,20) of the mouse event relative to the element returned by the locator.

    Clicks on a link, button, checkbox or radio button. If the click action causes a new page to load (like a link usually does), call waitForPageToLoad.""
```

Comment: Maybe you can give a bit more information? Like your IDE steps, part of the HTMl of the signout button and the full error message. The current question does not contain enough information to answer it.

Comment: i m a beginner, thats what all i got, the above funtionlities working wel like updating and all, but buttons like signout and home button for the same webpage is not working with IDE

Comment: Could you post the HTML of the buttons and the IDE code? There isn't enough here for anyone to help you.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>50000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>name= &quot;Sign Out&quot;</td>
 <td>sign out</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAt</td>
 <td>name=&quot;Sign Out&quot;</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=LoginName</td>
 <td>barney</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=Password</td>
 <td>barney</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>//button[@type='submit']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Answer (score 1):

I see in your selenese you're calling ClickAt with only one argument, the locator.
 clickAt name="Sign Out"

You can try using the plain click keyword:

```
<tr> <td>click</td> <td>name=&quot;Sign Out&quot;</td></tr>
```

Also you can try supplying coordinates for the clickAt keyword:

```
<tr> <td>clickAt</td> <td>name=&quot;Sign Out&quot;</td> <td>1,1</td> </tr>
```

I think either of these should resolve your error.

Edit: if you're using the IDE then put the coordinates in the box called Value, it's just below Target.

Cheers

Comment: thankyou very much, this will help me in future, as i m a beginner . i will ask a lot of questions in future